# Bash конструкция elif

Tags: linux, bash

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где косяк.

```
read -p "Would you like to find a only 1 named file or gzip's files by criterias? Type 'name' or 'criteria' word, please:" choice
if [$choice = name]
then read -p "Where 'find' need to look?" where
read -p "Name of file?" name
read -p "Index of file?" index
find $where -name $name -exec bash -c "mv -v {} {}-$(date +%Y%m%d)_$index|awk '{print \$3}'|sed 's/\`//'|sed ''s/\'//''|xargs gzip" \; -exec touch {} \; -exec chown nobody:nobody {} \; -exec ls -lh $where \;
else echo "Repeat your choice"
elif [$choice = criteria]
then read -p "Where 'find' need to look?" where
read -p "Size of file? (k for kylobytes, M for megabytes, G for gygabtyes)" size
read -p "Index of file?" index
find $where -size +$size -exec bash -c "mv -v {} {}-$(date +%Y%m%d)_$index|awk '{print \$3}'|sed 's/\`//'|sed ''s/\'//''|xargs gzip" \; -exec touch {} \; -exec chown nobody:nobody {} \; -exec ls -lh $where \;
else echo "Repeat your choice"
fi
```

Пишет, что ошибка на 10-й строчке, но не могу понять, почему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что ерунда написана. Конструкция if должна иметь вид:

```
if "condition" ; then "operators"
[elif "condition" ; then "operators"]*
[else "operators"]
fi
```

У Вас else идёт до elif, непонятно что имеется в виду.

Подозреваю, что это elif нужно заменить просто на if, а в конце поставить второе fi.

Comment: А почему в других источниках условия и операторы не берутся в двойные кавычки?

Comment: Это псевдокод, я взял в двойные кавычки, чтобы неслужебный код подсветился зелёным.

Квадратные скобки обозначают то, что можно опустить, а звёздочка — то, что предшествовавшая конструкция может повториться несколько раз.